# How to justify a text with Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I use Adobe Illustrator 2019 for Windows. Sometimes I would like to justify a long text (left and right alignment) in the same way as Windows Office.

[image]

Currently I work as follows. I write the text in Office Word and paste it directly into the file I'm working on. But I can't modify the text because Adobe Illustrator identifies me every single letter as if it were an image. A little animated guide to understand even better the procedure for me is important and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you simply paste text in Illustrator, it creates a text object. A text object can't be force justified in Illustrator. You must first create a text frame by drawing a box shape with the text tool. Click into the frame and paste in your text, then you can control justification.

[Added further explanation]
Illustrator allows you to use text in a number of ways. By default, when you paste text from the clipboard with nothing selected, Illustrator just drops the copied text as a basic text object. Text objects are good for single words or small phrases, but not for body copy because they have no defined boundaries. For that, you have to select the text tool from the tools panel and "draw" a text frame. With the text tool selected, click and drag a box from the top left to the lower right to create a new text frame. (Newer versions of Illustrator automatically fill the frame with placeholder text. Older versions just leave the frame empty.) Select the placeholder text (if necessary) and paste your copied text into the frame. You can drag the handles of the text frame to change its dimensions to suit your needs. Once the text is inside the frame, you can use the justification options located on the Paragraph panel to select your desired justification method.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, can I have an explanation more detailed? I'm probably wrong about something, but I've also tried your non-working alternative.

Comment: Answer updated. If this doesn't work for you, please post what you have and let us know where these instructions are failing.

Comment: The frame is a rectangle in the panel at the left?

Comment: I"m sorry, @Sebastiano, I am not sure what you are asking. The text frame in my image is the blue line surrounding the text. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Please, what is the buttom or the icon to create your blue line where I can put the text?

Comment: It's the type tool. I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use Windows. Alt+T (T as text) activates the different text options. Your application was rated and accepted with a green check mark. Thank you.

Comment: This explanation was super helpful! Thank you.